# dijit.layout.StackContainer sizes to first child

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm a complete newb to dojo, but not to JavaScript.

I am testing out functionality and trying to build a basic dijit.layout.StackContainer (both declaratively and programmatically). The is that I have is that my stack container is sized according to the size of the first child element. What I would like is to size it based on the size of the element I place it within. How can I do this? I've looked over the Reference Guide, API Docs, etc but nothing seemed to help. :(

Thanks in advance

The only way I have been able to get this to work is if I define the height property on the element I wish to attach my StackContainer, and then manually lookup the height property when declaring the style property of the StackContainer. Like so...

```
<div id="content" style="height: 100%; background-color: green;"></div>
<script>
    var domNode, controller, container;
    domNode = document.getElementById('content');
    controller = new StackController({
        containerId:"mainStack"
    }).placeAt(domNode);
    container = new StackContainer({
        id: "mainStack",
        isLayoutContainer: true,
        style: "background-color: yellow; height: "+domNode.style.height
    });
    container.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "Search for Images...",
        tooltip: "Click here to begin your search.",
        content: searchTemplate
    }));
    container.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "View Results..",
        tooltip: "After you search for a topic, click here to view your results.",
        content: resultTemplate
    }));
    container.placeAt(domNode);

    container.startup();
    controller.startup();
</script>
```

This works, but feels like a hack on my part due to lack of experience with dojo. Does anyone have any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `doLayout` property on your StackContainer to false.  Per the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/layout/StackContainer#doLayout):

```
doLayout
Defined by dijit/layout/StackContainer
If true, change the size of my currently displayed child to match my size
```

This would amount to

```
container = new StackContainer({
   id: "mainStack",
   isLayoutContainer: true,
   style: "background-color: yellow;",
   doLayout:false
});
```

You may also need `doLayout:false` on the children.

Comment: So this isn't exactly what I was shooting for, but doing this feels cleaner. However, I would need to have "overflow: auto" set on my original element so that children don't break out. What I was looking for was that the StackContainer would be sized to the height of the element which it is attached, and then the children would be confined to that height. By setting  "doLayout: false" it just breaks out the child elements.